# How to get 'Enter' key input

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So im using **Tkinter** to make a calculator and I want to be when you press the *ENTER* key it solves the equation.  How would I do that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a function to the `<Return>` event when it occurs in a widget. The following example will update the label when you press return:

```
import tkinter as tk

def solve(event):
    eq = equation.get()
    s = f"the solution for {eq} is ..."
    solution.configure(text=s)

root = tk.Tk()

equation = tk.Entry(root)
solution = tk.Label(root, anchor="w")

equation.pack(side="top", fill="x")
solution.pack(side="top", fill="x")

equation.bind("<Return>", solve)

root.mainloop()
```